# Dynamically adding a new jQuery slider causes the older sliders to not function.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is my code:

```
    newS = "#newS_"+g; //g is a unique number from an id
    document.getElementById('finderScroll').innerHTML +='<div id="newS_'+g+'"></div>'
       $(newS).slider({
              range: true,
              min: 0,
              max: 500,
              values: [ 75, 300 ],
              slide: function( event, ui ) {
              console.log( ui.values[ 0 ] + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                 }
              });
```

Each new slider works, but when I add another, the previous slider no longer functions. It causes it to no longer be draggable even though everything about each slider is unique. Does anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: It would help if you posted a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Way too much code to add a jsfiddle. It is importing JSON and drag and drop to init the new slider. I can make a small mockup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By updating `innerHTML` you essentially make the browser to rebuild your DOM from the scratch. Use `appendChild` instead, that will preserve the event handlers AND data attached to the existing elements.

In fact, I don't see why you cannot write like this:

```
$('#finderScroll').append($('<div>').attr('id', 'newS_' + g));
```

... as you already use jQuery. Also, I'd suggest rewriting the assigner block too: you don't need to traverse the DOM looking for that created element (with `$(newsG)`), as you can write this:

```
$('<div>').attr('id', 'news_' + g).slider({ ... })
    .appendTo($('#finderScroll'));
```

Comment: That is more efficient but the problem still exists.

Comment: Nevermind, I had some old code that was still adding to the innerHTML. I removed it and then it all worked. Cool, thanks!

Comment: It's ok. ) Just finished the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uWvX/) to illustrate this approach.